# Automatically sort an API list by name in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello I am new in the field of Vue,js and am stuck on a certain problem. I have an API list with different data points that I am trying to sort by `first_name` and Load onto the page:

```
<template>
  <div> 

    
    <div class="content-card">
      <h1 class="title">List of users</h1>



      <div v-for="peopleData in peopleDataList.data"  :key ="peopleData.id" class="people-data">
        <div @load="sort('first_name')" v-bind:class="[sortBy === 'first_name' ? sortDirection : '']">
  
        
          <div class="user-icon">
            <img :src="peopleData.avatar" alt="Connection lost please reload">
          </div>

          
          <div class="user-info">
            <div class="user-full_name"> 
              {{peopleData.first_name}}
              {{peopleData.last_name}}
            </div>

            <div class="user-email">
              <!-- {{peopleData.email}} -->
            </div>
          </div>
          
          
          <!-- make a mdel to display as menu with the data  -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>



export default {
  name: "List",


  data() {
    return {
      peopleDataList: [],
      sortBy: 'name',
      sortDirection: 'asc',
    };
  }, 


// automatically call the data 
  created() {
    this.getpeopleData();
  },


  methods: {
    getpeopleData() {
      fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => (this.peopleDataList = data));
    },



    sort: function(s){
      if(s === this.sortBy) {
        this.sortDirection = this.sortDirection === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
       }
        this.sortBy = s;
    }
  },

  watch: {
            sortedProducts: function(){
                return this.products.sort((p1,p2) => {
                    let modifier = 1;
                    if(this.sortDirection === 'desc') modifier = -1;
                    if(p1[this.sortBy] < p2[this.sortBy]) return -1 * modifier; if(p1[this.sortBy] > p2[this.sortBy]) return 1 * modifier;
                    return 0;
                });
            }
        },



};
</script>
```

I've seen multiple guides using `@click` to solve this problem but I wanted to have it automatically sort when its loaded. I am still new to Vue.js so please go easy on me.

Comment: Alright, it looks like it a bit too complex and not related to vue right now. Can you please edit your question and give us the API list as the input and the result that you want at the end ? Once we have sorted out how to sort it properly, we will plug it to Vue. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need <div @load ...
I recommend sorting the users in your getPeopleData() method, similar to this:

```
<template>
  <div class="initial-data-sort">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>NAME</th>
          <th>EMAIL</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
          <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        users: [],
        usersSorted: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getUsers() {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
          .then(response => {
            this.users = response.data;
            // Sort users
            this.users.sort(this.compareNames);
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      },
      compareNames(a, b) {
        const nameA = a.name.toLowerCase();
        const nameB = b.name.toLowerCase();

        let comparison = 0;
        if (nameA > nameB) {
          comparison = 1;
        } else if (nameA < nameB) {
          comparison = -1;
        }
        return comparison;
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.getUsers();
    }
  }
</script>
```

I sometimes keep a sorted version of the data array, hence the inclusion of 'usersSorted', but possibly not necessary in your case.

Comment: I'd recommend `this.users.splice().sort(this.compareNames)` to avoid mutability and copy the array rather than mutating the original one. https://doesitmutate.xyz/sort/